# Mobile view logo background colour in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, css

My website is http://fitnesslover.byethost18.com/

I’m using storefront theme. It shows perfectly in desktop. But when in mobile mode the background color behind the logo disappears. It takes the background color of the menu (white). I want the background color behind the logo as it is in the desktop and background color for menu as white. Just like it shows in desktop.

How do I do it?

I have added few css code in my child theme

```
/* Super menu underline color */

.main-navigation ul li:hover > a {
border-bottom: 4px solid #96588a;
}

/* Sub menu background color */

.menu li li {
background: #c7c7c7;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
color: #444;
filter: none;
margin: -1px 0 1px 0;
width: auto;
}

/* Reducing header height */

header#masthead {
padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Centering of logo and secondary navigation menu */

nav#site-navigation {
padding-top: 0px;
}

/* Super menu background color */
.storefront-primary-navigation{
background: white;
}
```

Comment: This question requires knowledge of the Storefront theme, so you have a better chance of getting an answer at their support line.

Comment: I posted the question on wordpress forum as well but no response yet

Answer (score 0):

To change css in mobile view you need `@media` in you css. To apply on mobile view use `@media` as shown below

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    Put your classes and IDs here

}
```

The above code will make your css apply only on those device whose Width is maximum of 768px in size.

You can use it with `min-width` also like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    Put your classes and IDs here

}
```

The above code will make your css apply only on those device whose Width is minimum of 768px, In other words width must be bigger than 768px.

In your case you wanna change logo's background then put your logo's `class/ID` in `@media` and select your desired properties of those `class/ID`. If it don't pick up your properties then try to use`!important` with property like this `background: #fff!important;`